# How can I update R from RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

I need to update R manually, in RStudio. Then I gone to: Tools -> Global options -> General. But I didn't see guidelines for updating.

Answer (score 0):

Just download a new R version from [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/) and install it on your system.

If you are on windows, check the installr package : [installr](https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/pandoc/installr.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can update R via point and click from RStudio. Either you download the new version manually from CRAN (it comes with an installer so you don't need to do anything by yourself) or you use the installR package on Windows or the updateR package on Mac: https://github.com/AndreaCirilloAC/updateR